# What is the best way to change externally referenced workbook table in bulk?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two workbooks: Report.xlsx and Master.xlsx. Report wb has 3,587 cells with references to Table1 in Master wb. I was doing a lot of manipulation and merging of data in Master that I have since moved to SQL Server, and now I want to import a view that is the exact same data set that's already in Table1.

My question is how do I replace Table1 with the view from SQL Server and maintain the cell references that are in place in Report? I understand that renaming Table1 in Master will update the formula references in Report, so importing a new table and calling that Table1 won't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
3. Search for "Table1" and replace it with "Master" (or what your Table is named)